# MongoDB: Implicit and explicit AND operator behaviour

Tags: mongodb, logical-operators, mongo-shell

Considering the following exercise from MongoDB official course:

> How many companies in the sample_training.companies dataset were
>
> either founded in 2004 [and] either have the social category_code [or]
> web category_code, [or]
>
> were founded in the month of October [and]
> also either have the social category_code [or] web category_code?

I came across 3 posible solutions, with one of them giving an unexpected result I'd like to understand:

1. The most verbose and close to the textual assignment solution, with result **149** (the correct result):

```
db.companies.find({ 
    $or: [
        {$and: [{ "founded_year": 2004 }, 
            { $or: [{ "category_code": "social" }, { "category_code": "web" }] 
            }] 
        },
        {$and: [{ "founded_month": 10 }, 
            { $or: [{ "category_code": "social" }, { "category_code": "web" }] 
            }] 
        }
    ] 
}).count()
```

2. A shortened solution, applying logical equivalence to the clauses, also with result **149**:

```
db.companies.find({
    $and: [
        {$or: [{"category_code":"social"}, {"category_code":"web"}]}, 
        {$or: [{"founded_year":2004}, {"founded_month": 10}]}
    ]
}).count()
```

3. And a third solution, which replicates the second tring to take advantage of the implicit and operator:

```
db.companies.find({
    $or: [{"category_code":"social"}, {"category_code":"web"}], 
    $or: [{"founded_year":2004}, {"founded_month": 10}]
}).count()
```

This third solution's result is **668**, so it is clearly not functioning as expected. The question is why taking the AND out, which should be redundant, ends up in a change of computation.

Mongosh version is 1.6.0 and it's connected to an Atlas free cluster

Comment: The 3rd version contains syntax error. Would you please help to provide your working version?

Comment: Mongosh version is 1.6.0 and it's connected to an Atlas free cluster. It runs ok in my case, apart from the confusing result offcourse.